# attaching screenshot to allure report using playwright

Tags: allure, playwright, playwright-test

How might I be able to attach screenshot to allure report using MS Playwright

```
test('basic test', async ({ page }) => {

  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
  const screen1 = await page.screenshot({path: './screenshots/screenshot.png',fullPage: true});
  allure.screenshot('screenShot', screen1, 'image/png');
  const title = await page.locator('.navbar__inner .navbar__title');
  await expect(title).toHaveText('Playwright');
  //await title.screenshot({path: './screenshots/title.png'});
  await page.close();
});
```

I already have allure installed using `npm i -D allure-playwright`

Yet I cannot get ad hoc screenshots attached to the rendered allure report during the test step.

Comment: You can attach additional attachments see here: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testinfo#test-info-attachments